# Видео в андроид приложение

Tags: java, android, видео

Реализовал в своем приложении возможность просмотра видео через url используя VideoView.

```
videoView = (VideoViewCustom) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
mediaController = new MediaController(this);

videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(bundle.getString("incPath")));
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        videoView.start();
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

});
```

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Многие пользователи жалуются, что не проигрываются некоторые ролики и фильмы могут в разное время выдать ошибку (video cannot be played). Все ролики в том числе и фильмы (.mp4 H.264). Ради тестов я скачивал не работающие ролики и смотрел их на этих устройствах в обычном режиме (т.е. вне приложения) и никаких ошибок не возникало. Я так понимаю проблема не в кодеках.
Параллельно с просмотром роликов я пинговал сервер и пинги не пропадали в то время как появлялся все тот же пресловутый (sorry video cannot be played).

У меня есть 2 варианта

1. Может мне MediaPlayer использовать вместо VideoView?
2. Или может просто плеер хтмл5 впихнуть в webview.

Может перечисленное выше покажется бредом, и не известно в целом будет ли повторяться ошибка, но я просто уже не знаю куда копать.
Если, кто знает пожалуйста, подскажите мне альтернативу (если она есть). И в целом как с этим бороться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android поддерживает не все видео кодеки и не все форматы видео. Кроме того есть ограничения на streaming видео через HTTP, так что, то что видео идет на вашем девайсе ровно ничего не означает. Более того некоторые аппараты могут поддерживать сверх стандартного списка (не исключено что и меньше стандартного списка). Список стандартных ограничений [здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Я бы рекомендовал отловить ошибку стриминга и интеллигентно сообщить юзеру, что есть проблема. Для отлова ошибки стриминга можно использовать функцию `VideoView.setOnErrorListener()`

Comment: Спасибо, что отозвались ! Но у меня не стриминг, у меня банально читает по юрл. Пробовал отлавливать. Скажу так, отлавливает эта функция очень и очень плохо (знаю из личного опыта). Скажите, пожалуйста, а предложенные выше варианта могут рассматриваться ? В частности  html5